# Delete photos and videos already uploaded by Dropbox Camera Upload

Tags: dropbox

I am using Dropbox Camera Upload on my Android smartphone. I would like to remove files from Android Gallery once they have been uploaded to Dropbox. I don't mind if it happens automatically and immediately or I need to run some app manually now and then. Is it possible, or is there some other way to free up smartphone camera storage when using Dropbox Camera Upload?

Right now I can only do it manually, by comparing Gallery contents with what I see in Dropbox on my desktop computer. It is tedious for hundreds of files, especially for videos (Dropbox and Gallery show different frames in preview, so I need to play every video on smartphone and on computer). Dropbox also changes file names, e.g. for one photo I have now:

- Gallery: 20171208_174736.jpg
- Dropbox: 2017-12-08 17.47.35.jpg

For videos it's even worse, as one uses the video start time and another the end time.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [This app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.dropsync) claims to *upload and delete*. Not tried by me

Comment: Google photos has that feature. It's called 'free up space' it automatically detects uploaded pictures and deletes them from your phone. I don't have Dropbox but i suggest you look for a similar open in the app.